# unable to start ORACLE database

Tags: oracle

My application is running on Oracle Database which hosts 3 database instances. All of sudden one of my database instance is not running. when connected through sysdba it says "connected to idle instance". Here are the activities performed

Oracle version:Release 11.2.0.4.0

1. `sudo su - oracle`
2. `export ORACLE_SID=testdev1`
3. `sqlplus / AS SYSDBA`

> Connected to an idle instance.

4. `shutdown immediate`

> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>
> ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist Linux-x86_64 Error: 2:
>   No such file or directory

5. `startup`

> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
>
> ORA-01565: error in identifying file
>   '+DATADG/testdev1/spfiltestdev1.ora'
>
> ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file
>   +DATADG/testdev1/spfiletestdev1.ora
>
> ORA-29701: unable to connect to Cluster Synchronization Service

can anyone help me what is the issue ?

Comment: Sounds like ASM or a related service might not be running?

Comment: how should I check for ASM ?

Comment: 'ps -ef |grep -i ASM'  also 'ps -ef|grep pmon' and see if an ASM instance is listed. Also 'set ORACLE_SID=+ASM' then 'sqlplus / as sysasm'

Comment: I usually use `source /usr/local/bin/oraenv` before `sqlplus`.  This will add all of the other environmental variables that might be needed.

Comment: Also, check your cluster status with `crsctl check crs`

Comment: unfortunately my database ASM service is not running. I restarted and everything worked. thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately my database ASM service is not running. I restarted and everything worked. thanks all for your help